# Queue push not working

Tags: c, queue

I am trying to implement some queue operations but it seems that the front remains NULL even after pushing all the elements. In the main function i just read some elements and push them in the queue. My code:

```
typedef struct nod
{
    int info;
    struct nod *link;
}tnod;
tnod *front=NULL,*rear=NULL;
void push(tnod *front,int item)
{
    tnod *tmp;
    tmp=malloc(sizeof(tnod));
    if(tmp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memorie indisponibila\n");
        return;
    }
    tmp->info = item;
    tmp->link=NULL;
if(front==NULL)      /*daca stiva e goala*/
        {front=tmp; printf("%d",front->info);}
else
    rear->link = tmp;
    rear=tmp;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are shadowing the global variable `front` with the front in the function: `void push(tnod *front,int item)`.

When you change `front` in the function the global `front` doesn't change. Change the variable names.

If you are by any chance passing the global variable front as the first parameter in the push function, then by changing the parameter in the function will not change the global front.

Comment: Will it work if i just remove that parameter from the function?

Comment: @Andy If you don't need that parameter, you can remove it. Look at how are you calling the function.

Comment: Which variable name should i change? The one of the global or the ones in the function?